# How do I insert Greek/Hebrew characters into a question or answer?

Tags: discussion, language

I've spent the last hour browsing the site for tips on this practical question. So if it's been previously answered I apologise, but I have made an effort.

Comment: Have you been trying to do this and it didn't work somehow? In my experience, any character I can either generate on my computer (my keyboard can be flipped to Gr./Heb.) or copy from elsewhere ([Biblegateway](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=gen+1&version=WLC) is one online source that gets used frequently, but any Bible software will also do) is rendered just fine in SE Q&As (even if [the font is less than ideal](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/956/3555)).

Comment: If you don't already have your preferred sources for original language texts online (for copy-paste purposes), do check out the Meta thread about [good reference works](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/640/). There are a lot of helpful resources listed there.

Comment: Check out [branah.com](https://www.branah.com). It has a Greek and Hebrew keyboard along with keyboards for many other languages. Once you are done typing you can just copy and paste your text into your question or answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just type them like you would any other character. Posts on SE are encoded using Unicode which can handle just about any character from any known alphabet.

The most common way to do this is using an input device configured for the language of your choice. Almost all operating systems have a system to add keyboard layouts for other languages. Adding more than one typically also adds a menu somewhere and often a keyboard shortcut to switch between them. Adding Greek and Hebrew keyboard layouts to your operating system's region or language settings should do the trick.

If you are unfamiliar with the language in question and need to pick out a couple of letters, some operating systems have an on-screen keyboard system that will show you a popup keyboard that you can click on letters. This helps when you need to scratch out one word and aren't fluent at typing it the target language.

Also for single words or characters you can often find them in some other source you're working with and copy/paste them into your post.

Comment: I'm using an Apple Mac laptop and in the last 10 minutes have learned heaps about the Character Palette, which I never even knew existed. Silly, because I'm familiar at work with the Windows Character Map. Thanks for taking the time to help out.